# Split badges in the 'recent' view

Tags: feature-request, badges

There are badges grouped by name in all views. But it will be good to split badges in the `recent` view, to see all the badges in the inversed chronological order, not only the last badges in a group.

It will be better to see

- Yearling
- Famous Question
- Yearling
- Citizen Patrol

instead of

- Yearling × 2
- Famous Question
- Citizen Patrol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's already provided in your activity tab in your profile. Choose the "badges" sub-tab and you'll get a chronological list of all your badges, no grouping.

For example: [badge activity for Errandir on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/274205/errandir?tab=activity&sort=badges)

I would rather not split the badges in the main badge tab, that summary view is rather nice IMO.

Comment: I wanted the feature suggested by the OP. But I forgot the activity tab. So there is no need to implement it on main badge tab now.